# launch sphinx commands "make clean" and "make html" from django.core.management call_command

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx

Is there any way to launch sphinx commands "make clean" and "make html" from from django.core.management call_command?

I need to refresh docs generated by sphinx every day, so I was thinking to use django-crontab to set a daily job. This job would call "make clean" and "make html" to automatically generate doc.

But, maybe there is a simpler way to refresh docs generated by sphinx every day?

Thanks!